# EF Core 5 Many To Many relationships not working as should according to docs

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#many-to-many), EF Core 5.0 supports many-to-many relationships without explicitly mapping the join table.

I'm having issues with the below in EF Core 5.0.9:

```
public List<Booking> GetAllBookingsForDay(int day, DateTime bookingDate)
{
     return db.Bookings
    .Where(w => w.IsActive == true & w.IsDeleted == false & w.DayOfWeek == day & w.Time >= bookingDate)
    .Include(c => c.Students)
    .ToList();
}
```

I have included `Students` as part of the query.

`Booking.cs`

```
public class Booking
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? DayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BookingDate { get; set; }
    public bool? IsAbsent { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Time { get; set; }
    public bool? HasCheckedIn { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }  // notice this
    public int? StudentId { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

`Student.cs`

```
public class Student
{   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Type { get; set; }
    public int? TeamId { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
    public decimal? Weight { get; set; }
    public decimal? Height { get; set; }
    public int? Gender { get; set; }
    public string? Photo { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; } // notice here my link back 
     to bookings
   ...
 }
```

Nuget packages:

[image]

SQL database:

[image]

When I inspect the booking table, its empty does EF not automatically add into BookingStudent if so how do I tell ef core to add in the student? I have saved their StudentId into booking so why has it not created an entry.

It Created the booking table entry

[image]

In My head I should see the values 10 and 72 in booking student should I not.

But not the booking Student Entry ?. According to the docs it creates it automatically yeah but what about saving entries does it not still do that automatically.

[image]

At this stage I have not placed anything in my DBContext on create method as the docs say u dont need that any more???

This is how I save my student. As you see am filling in the foreign key of StudentId.

```
Booking newBooking = new Booking();
newBooking.DayOfWeek = DayNumber;
newBooking.BookingDate = BookingDate;
newBooking.Time=Helpers.Dates.GetDateZeroTime(selectedBookingDate.Date).Add(timePicker.Time);
newBooking.StudentId = StudentId;
newBooking.HasCheckedIn = false;
newBooking.IsActive = true;
newBooking.IsDeleted = false;
newBooking.IsAbsent = false;
await api.AddToBooking(newBooking);
await DisplayAlert(Constants.AppName, "Booking Created For Student", "OK");
```

My Add to booking which the api is calling in the web api is.

```
public Booking AddBooking(Booking  booking)
{
    db.Bookings.Add(booking);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return booking;
}
```

**Edit 2**

Is this what u mean

```
//Do i need to put the second param in for Student here ?
public Booking AddBooking(Booking booking, Student student)
{
        booking.Students.Add(student);
        db.Bookings.Add(booking);

        db.SaveChanges();
        return booking;
}
```

Comment: What is the question or the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a many-to-many relationship, why do you have a `StudentId` property on `Booking`?

Remove the property first:

```
public class Booking
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? DayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BookingDate { get; set; }
    public bool? IsAbsent { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Time { get; set; }
    public bool? HasCheckedIn { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

And then add the student you want (which will have an ID) to the `ICollection` of students you have for a booking.

`booking.Students.Add(student);`

That will trigger the EF many-many relationship.

Something like this:

```
var student = new Student { ... };

var newBooking = new Booking {
    Student = new List<Student> { student },
    ...
};

await api.AddToBooking(newBooking);
```

Comment: So then I would have to pass both Booking and Student through my booking AddTOBooking method would I ?

Comment: Please see my comments and eidts above

Comment: @csharpdude77 You would have to add the student to the `Students` collection of the booking - I've added some extra supporting code :)

Comment: Thanks I went with your suggesiton and combined them into one model so that I can pass them into my controller as one entity this has worked thanks

Comment: Question though if booking student has only StudentId and Booking Id why is it asking for the rest of parameters at the client side when i goto add the student to book.students.add  I could be updating a student as well

Comment: In that case, you will retrieve the booking from the DB, update the student in the list and then save the booking (without adding anything to the collection).

Comment: But at first the student may not have a booking bookings only come after

Comment: Then the student can be added separately without a booking set and a booking can be added with any empty collection - that's the beauty of a many-many relationship